# woocommerce redirect to checkout is not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have added a product in cart programatically and then want to redirect the user to checkout page and skip the product page and cart page. Product is added successfully but it does not go to checkout page and displays a blank page with no errors. This happens only when I clear my browser cashe. second time it works fine. The user comes from a custom link to product page. I want that when user is on product page, the product should automatically added and user should be redirected to checkout page.  Here is my code

```
add_action('template_redirect','redirect_if_cart_loaded', 10, 2);
  function redirect_if_cart_loaded(){
    global $woocommerce;
  if(is_product() && sizeof( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents ) == 0){

    echo $pooduct_id = get_the_ID();

    //check if product already in cart
    if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
     $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
}
    // if product not found, add it

        WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $pooduct_id );
        echo sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ); // this gives 1. means product is added
    if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
     wp_redirect( WC()->cart->get_checkout_url() );
     exit;
}


    }
  }
```

Comment: What version of woocommerce do you use?

Comment: If you have a blank page, you can have a look at your apache/ngninx/php error logs, you are likely to see a php fatal error somewhere

Comment: what is the result of echo WC()->cart->get_checkout_url() ; ? It might be an empty string; and your redirect would not even be used

Comment: any progress in your development ?

Comment: that functions prints checkout page url. However you solution has worked @ced

Comment: but its not working with wc_get_checkout_url(), it worked with get_checkout_url()

Comment: If you are using Woocommerce 2, use get_checkout_url. If you are using Woocommerce 3; it is advised to use wc_get_checkout_url , https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/annotation-group-deprecated.html

Comment: But whatever works for you works for you :)

Comment: thanks @Cedric. I am having another problem with woocommerce. Hope you can help me. How to get value of woocommerce stripe payment fields via jquery when I hit complete payment button? Remember woocommerce stipe payment gateway form in integrated in iframe. Should I create a new ticket for you?

Comment: The best way to get a quick answer is to create a new 'Question'/ticket :)

Comment: can you check this question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52764202/how-to-get-value-of-woocommerce-stripe-payment-form-that-is-integrated-in-iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
if ( !function_exists( 'wc_get_checkout_url' ) ) { 
    require_once '/includes/wc-core-functions.php'; 
} 

$result = wc_get_checkout_url();
```

use wc_get_checkout_url instead of get_checkout_url, as get_checkout_url is deprecated